# How can i disable these errors in the webdriverChromeOptions in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, bots

[8952:21640:0211/174219.827:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(962)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
[8952:21640:0211/174220.764:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(962)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[11424:15804:0211/174222.612:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [17:42:22.612] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[11424:15804:0211/174222.615:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [17:42:22.614] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[11424:15804:0211/174222.626:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [17:42:22.626] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[11424:15804:0211/174222.627:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [17:42:22.627] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor

How can i avoid these errors?
My code works fine and these errors are useless, how can i remove them using the webdriver.chrome.options()

I also have a problem with the headers.
It will not show the chrome driver at the start, however when I input something to make the bot search the website, it then shows.

I am currently using options.add_Argument('--headless')
And for SSL errors i have shown, im using options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors') however it still doesn't work.

Comment: This is using selenium btw

Comment: As general programing practice, I would strongly advise you not to disable the errors. Better to take the time and figure out how to address them properly.

Answer (score 0):

Using chrome driver exe or other browser exe are out of fashion on selenium automation. if you use web driver manager you don't need to download and set the path for exe files for different browser

[WebDriver Manager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)